# Description Validation Rule Help

Tags: contact, object

I have to create a validation rule "n/a should never be placed inside a description field" and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOT(ISBLANK(Description_Field__c)) && CONTAINS(Description_Field__c, 'n/a') replace field name with your field apiname

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need null check here also you might need to consider making it case insensitive.

so your validation rule will be something like below

```
CONTAINS(LOWER(Description_Field__c),'n/a')
```